# Use conditional inside $.each function to create array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to iterate over the elements of an array and if a condition is true I want to create a new array.

Example: I have an array called Messages whose elements are objects and I want to check if the id attribute equals 5. If yes create a new array only consisting of this object.

```
messages = [{
  "id": 10,
  "body": "hello!"
}, {
  "id": 21,
  "body": "hola!"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "body": "ciao!"
}];

var message5 = [];
var dataObj = {};

$.each(messages, function(index, value) {
  if (value.id == 5) {
    dataObj[index] = value;
  }
});

message5.push(dataObj[index]);
```

I want my result to be:

```
message5 = [
 {
  "id": 5,
  "body": "ciao!"
 }
]
```

Comment: what is your question? Do you have any problem doing it?

Comment: @Nadir I state at the bottom what my result needs to be. Obviously I cannot achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `Array.prototype.filter` at this context,

```
var message5 = messages.filter(function(itm){
  return itm.id == 5;
});

console.log(message5);  //[{"id": 5,"body": "ciao!"}]
```

If you want it to be more concise then you could use ES6 `Arrow function`,

```
var message5 = messages.filter(itm => itm.id == 5);
console.log(message5);  //[{"id": 5,"body": "ciao!"}]
```

But note that, the above code is similar to,

```
var message5 = messages.filter(function(itm){
  return itm.id == 5;
}.bind(this)); //Arrow function will automatically bind its lexical scope to it.
```

Comment: What if I want my message5 to be an object instead of an array?

Comment: @mosmic Then approach for that would be different. do you want me to write it now? :)

Comment: @mosmic Can you show me what is the expected result? Just give a sample

Comment: `message5 = {{"id":5,"body":"ciao!"}}`

Answer (score 2):

try to use filter:

```js
var messages = [{
  "id": 10,
  "body": "hello!"
}, {
  "id": 21,
  "body": "holla!"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "body": "ciao!"
}];
var message5 = messages.filter(function(message) {
  return message.id == 5;
});
alert(JSON.stringify(message5));
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var newArr = messages.filter( function(value){

   return value.id == 5;

} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Array filter() method

```
messages.filter(function(msg){return msg['id'] === 5})
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach completely in jQuery could be:

```js
$(function () {
  var messages = [{
    "id": 10,
    "body": "hello!"
  }, {
    "id": 21,
    "body": "holla!"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "body": "ciao!"
  }];
  var dataObj = [];

  $.each(messages, function (index, value) {
    if (value.id == 5) {
      dataObj.push(messages[index]);
    }
  });
  $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(dataObj, 4, 4));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="result" style="width: 250px;height: 100px"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind. Obviously filter function simplifies everything, but your answer is very helpful because I see my mistake now.